# Include product count within text field tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a search function and within the search function I would like to show the number of products that exist in the database on the right hand side, so it would look something like this:

---

Search................................................................................................................................1000 products

---

The dots are just to represent space.

I have the following code:

Index.html.erb

```
<div class="search">
  <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: "Search...", 
    id: "search_field" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= @products.count(:all) %>
<%= "Product".pluralize(@products.count(:all)) %>
```

How do I integrate the count function into the text_field_tag? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the count displayed in the text field tag but aligned to the right whilst the word "search" is aligned to the left?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I'm struggling with this. Is there somewhere online you've seen this?

Comment: No. It's a design feature a web designer has suggested for my upcoming app. I'm new to Rails and web development in general. I was thinking this could be done, but with CSS so it seems as if the count is within the search box, but actually it isn't. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have count inside the textfield and aligned towards the right with content on the left.

You can have a wrapper to search input and count and style in such a way that it will be visible as one input field. I have made a demo, you will get the idea and then can improve on it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="search-wrap">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search....."/> 
  <span class="count">1000 Products</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#search-wrap { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; }
#search-wrap input[type="text"] {  float: left; width: 85%; border: 0; padding: 2px;}
#search-wrap span.count{ font-size: 12px; color: #444; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/48q1uLgt/1/)

Comment: Thanks for helping out and creating the demo, very helpful.